# OES_texture_float in WebGL on Mobile

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, opengl-es-2.0

I made deferred shading renderer in WebGL using OES_texture_float texture to store G-buffer data.

This feature clearly works in browsers of PC(Chrome,Firefox,Safari,Edge...)
But, this G-buffer seems not working in Mobile browser.

I tried to find out the reason, but I couldn't make it. This is how I did for debugging this.

- Check OES_texture_float supported or NOT.

Of course I did this. And I made sure my devices for debugging is supporting OES_texture_float.
I tried to getExtension and that method didn't return undefined.

And I also checked out the website for check WebGL extension compatibility(http://renderingpipeline.com/webgl-extension-viewer/).

- I tried to fetch the pixels of the floating value texture with readPixels

I couldn't do this for mobile browser. But,in the Chrome in PC, readPixels to read floating value texture works correctly.

I guess readPixels to these types of texture is not ensured to work even if OES_texture_float was supported.

I know this is very hard to answer, but I couldn't paste my code here since these are very huge. And now I guess OES_texture_float is just supporting fetching texture value from texture like`texture2D(floatingTexture,uv)` and not made sure to use for rendering the texture itself.

I want any suggestion to debug. And, if you know any sample using floating value texture and working in mobile, please paste the url to work. I want to inspect it.

Comment: Oh I didn't write what devices I used to debug on mobile. I used iPhone6SPlus and ASUS zenfone(I don't remember version number of zenfone.).

Comment: Do you get any warnings in the console using [remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) ?
Afaik you should be able to `readPixels` of floating point textures if they're supported, however you should check and enable the `WEBGL_color_buffer_float` extension if you're rendering to a floating point texture. [See the last point in the Overview section of the extension spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_texture_float/).

Comment: Checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31974179/4168648. Also you may be able to workaround the problem by avoiding floats in your G-buffer. There are various packing strategies available depending on what you want to store in the G-buffer. Also check if your device supports MRT. If MRT is not supported then the chance of drawing floats are ~0%.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know there was such another extension `WEBGL_color_buffer_float`. I wonder this is the reason....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you check that you can render to a floating point texture? I don't think you can in mobile.

After you create your framebuffer with a floating point texture attached are you calling `gl.checkFramebufferStatus` and checking that the results is `gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE`? If it's not complete then the hardware does not support rendering to a floating point texture.

Comment: Exactly this is the answer! But, why browser would return null when call gl.getExtension("WEBGL_color_buffer_float") even if the browser support that feature?

Comment: No browsers that I know of have bothered to implement `WEBGL_color_buffer_float`. It's a long story. Basically they added `OES_texture_float` and people started rendering to floating point textures after checking the framebuffer status. It was only later someone pointed out that `OES_texture_float` is not enough to allow rendering to float textures because the spec says colors are clamped 0.0 to 1.0.  So they added `WEBGL_color_buffer_float` but actually enforcing it would have broken many existing pages so it's not implemented. As such it's not a *ratified* extension